# Applications Won't Install Due To Failed Previous Install

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, synaptic

An application that never finished installing is preventing me from getting new applications and i can't seem to fix this.

How do i fix my issue? Please note that I cannot install via either the package manager or Add/Remove Applications.

Comment: Please add which **Ubuntu** version.  What command-line options have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Try to open a terminal and enter `sudo apt-get -f install`

This command will try to correct any dependency issues that are left over from a previous attempt.  If it finds such issues, you will be asked if you want to download some dependencies; answer "yes."